# Water Box with n Liter

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science, contest-math, recursive-algorithms

I ran into a basic challenging problem. I see an high school local math Olympiad question.

we have a box that keep n Liter water. each time we extract 1/k Water from box. how many times (minimum) we should do it to see remaining water in box is lower or equal to 1 Liter . (k>2).

I need a creative approach for solving it. :)

Math Man Please Help Me !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Outline:** What about going for non-creative? If we now have an amount $a$ of water, then after one removal we have $a\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)$. 
So after $q$ removals, starting from $n$, we have
$$n\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^q.$$
We want
$$n\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^q\le 1.$$
Finding the smallest $q$ is a job for the **logarithm**.  I would be more comfortable solving the equivalent inequality
$$\left(\frac{k}{k-1}\right)^q\ge n.\tag{1}$$

**Added:** Use your favourite kind of logarithm. Mine is the natural logarithm (base $e$), but if you really want to, use base $10$. Whatever base $b\gt 1$ we use, call the resulting logarithm by the name $\log$.

Then Inequality (1) can be rewritten as
$$q\log\left(\frac{k}{k-1}\right)\ge \log n,$$
or equivalently
$$q\ge \frac{\log n}{\log\left(\frac{k}{k-1}\right)}.\tag{2}$$
For brevity, let $w$ be the right-hand side of (2). So we want $q\ge w$. The **smallest** $q$ that will work is $\lceil w\rceil$, the smallest integer which is $\ge w$.

Comment: You are welcome. From the last equation, try to do it on your own. If you tell me what you got, I can tell you whether you are right.

Comment: Use your favourite brand of logarithm. I would suggest natural logarithm (base $e$) but if you really want to use base $10$. We want $q\log(k/(k-1))\ge\log n$, so $q\ge (\log n)/(\log(k/(k-1))$. Call the ugly number we just got by the name $w$. Then actually our answer is $\lceil w\rceil$, the smallest integer which is greater than or equal to $w$.

Comment: dear Nicolas, I'm sorry, but I confused. I don't get how you calculate logarithm. would you please wrote it in a larger space?

Comment: You are right, math in comments is pretty cramped! I have transferred the information to the answer.

Comment: thanks so much from your kindly help.

Comment: You are welcome.